# Looking for young adult space scifi about pendant

Tags: story-identification, young-adult, space

Looking for the title of a young adult sci fi in space.

The cover was blacks purples and blues, I think.

There was a drawing of a pendant and an obscure godlike figure. All I remember is 
there was a spaceship and they had to obtain a pendant or gemstone, but it was called something else, a word that is not used in common vernacular.

Comment: Welcome to SFF:SE. We recommend having a look at the [tour](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/tour), which contains helpful hints for using the site. As this is a story identification question, you can also have a look at this [guide](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/tags/story-identification/info).